# C Union, Padding of array inside the struct

Tags: c, struct, stm32, unions

I have code as below:

```
  struct MODER_BITS
{   __IO uint32_t MODER0:2;
    __IO uint32_t MODER1:2;
    __IO uint32_t MODER2:2;
    __IO uint32_t MODER3:2;
    __IO uint32_t MODER4:2;
    __IO uint32_t MODER5:2;
    __IO uint32_t MODER6:2;
    __IO uint32_t MODER7:2;
    __IO uint32_t MODER8:2;
    __IO uint32_t MODER9:2;
    __IO uint32_t MODER10:2;
    __IO uint32_t MODER11:2;
    __IO uint32_t MODER12:2;
    __IO uint32_t MODER13:2;
    __IO uint32_t MODER14:2;
    __IO uint32_t MODER15:2;
};

typedef union {
    __IO uint32_t all;
    struct MODER_BITS bit;
}MODER_REG;
```

then I am able to use the GPIO struct

```
typedef struct
{
  MODER_REG MODER_REG;
  //__IO uint32_t MODER    ;/*!< GPIO port mode register,                  
  __IO uint32_t OTYPER;   /*!< GPIO port output type register,            */
  __IO uint32_t OSPEEDR;  /*!< GPIO port output speed register,          */
  __IO uint32_t PUPDR;    /*!< GPIO port pull-up/pull-down register,     */
  __IO uint32_t IDR;      /*!< GPIO port input data register,            */
  __IO uint32_t ODR;      /*!< GPIO port output data register,           */
  __IO uint32_t BSRR;     /*!< GPIO port bit set/reset register,          */
  __IO uint32_t LCKR;     /*!< GPIO port configuration lock register,     */
  __IO uint32_t AFR[2];   /*!< GPIO alternate function registers,     */
} GPIO_TypeDef;
```

Then I can use this definition like this:

```
GPIOA->MODER_REG.bit.MODER0=0x2;
```

Is there some way to use the array inside the struct MODER_REG? To used the GPIO like this:

```
GPIOA->MODER_REG.bit.MODER[0]=0x2;
```

How should looks like definition of

```
struct MODER_BITS{
 __IO uint32_t MODER[?]:? //options     
}
```

PS:
__IO is just a macro of volatile

Please advice.

Comment: Note that for the headers that follow CMSIS standard, you don't need to know where each field starts, as the headers provide individual defines for each bit. So if you need to set bits of the MODER9 field, there will be a defines like `GPIO_MODER_MODER9_0` and `GPIO_MODER_MODER9_1`. This standard is followed for all registers. Moreover new versions of the headers  provide `..._Pos` macros with the bit position of the fields - for example `GPIO_MODER_MODER9_Pos` from STM32F0 headers.

Comment: Yes I note that inside the  stm32f411xe.h there are definition of this BITS, but I prefer  this new version of macro with : GPIO_MODER_MODER9_Pos . I did't know about this new version. Thanks ! What you think about this solution with C++ template and  std:bitset ?

Comment: Too much work for too little gain - in my opinion (; I think in C++ you should just use te registers at the lowest level and above that use some higher-level interfaces. With that approach the driver for most of peripherals is pretty short anyway, and whether you use `GPIOA->MODER_REG.bit.MODER[0]=0x2;` or `gpioSetModer(GPIOA, 0, 0x02);` is nothing more than a formatting difference (again - in my opinion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way. C doesn't allow arrays of bits.

However, you can still access the original word by using bitmask:

```
GPIOA->MODER_REG.all = (GPIOA->MODER_REG.all)&(~3<<0)|(2<<0);
```

The first part resets the bits at position 0, the second part sets then to value 2.

Comment: Ok that means there is no sens to used this like that because orginally is :   __IO uint32_t MODER;   I just want  to avoid checking  from where the Bits are started in reference manual

Comment: @MateuszTocha - A macro or a function is to access the bits is just as clear as a named member.

Comment: What about C++?

Comment: @MateuszTocha - What about it? It has a [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)